# Rails-api cant find my css files in public folder

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I am running rails api with angularJS. my root is set to :   `root :to => "main#Home"`

and MainController is defined as  :

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def Home
    render :file => "public/angular/app/index.html"
  end
end
```

in html file i link to css and some js files, and those files is in public directory. I want to avoid using rails app/assets folder since rails will only be used as API, so all the templates will be loaded by angular, i just need a way to load index page with all the styling and js.

What have i done wrong?

Edit:

One of the errors :

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"):
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: updated my question with one of the errors

Comment: and your view file please, and the tree if yiur assets and public folder

Comment: anyway, that error is saying that you don't have bower_components/... in public folder